# HTML link title atrribute tooltip internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, tooltip, title

It seems that Internet Explorer 8 does not give a tooltip when a link has a title.
This is however W3.org valid and other browsers do give a tooltip. What's the proper way to make sure that iE8 also gives a tooltip with the title on a link?

```
 <a href="contact/" title="Contact us for bla">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should display the title.

The only problem with IE is that it displays alt as titles (but titles are handled correctly) while it should display nothing when there's only an alt value.

Do you have a test page?

Comment: Found the cause... spans result in no tooltip :

          <a href="contact/" title="Contact us for bla"><span>Contact</span></a>