# My css tooltip using hover doesn't work on IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, hover, tooltip

I'm using a tooltip basen on css hover property over an image, the page it'w working just fine on IE10, IE11, Chrome and Firefox but on IE8 (haven't tested on IE9) the tooltip symply won't display when I mouse over an image.

I'm looking for some suggestions on what to add to my web page to make this work.

```
CAPSULAS <div id="imgel" class="imgel">
        <div id="imgem" class="imgem">
           <img src="/images/ER.jpg" width="16" height="16" border="0" />
           <span>Valorar relación riesgo/beneficio en el embarazo.</span>
        </div>
        <div id="imgla" class="imgla">
           <img src="/images/LC.jpg" width="16" height="16" border="0" />
           <span>No usar en la lactancia.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the css

```
.imgel {
    display:inline;
    width:60px;
    margin-left:5px;  
    }
.imgem {
    width:19px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:4px;
    }  
.imgla {
    width:19px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:4px;
    }     
.imgem span {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:-5px;
    background:#F8F8FF;
    /*width:80px;*/
    width:auto;
    height:18px;
    border:1px solid #404040;
    font-size:7pt;
    line-height:160%; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space:nowrap;   
    }  
.imgla span {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    top:-5px;
    background:#F8F8FF;
    /*width:80px;*/
    width:auto;
    height:18px;
    border:1px solid #404040;
    font-size:7pt;
    line-height:160%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space:nowrap;
    } 
.imgem:hover span {
    visibility:visible;
    }
.imgla:hover span {
    visibility:visible;
    }
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this answer:

[Title tooltip is not shown when span is child of anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246818/title-tooltip-is-not-shown-when-span-is-child-of-anchor)

I applied the DOCTYPE header and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `visibility:hidden` 
use 
`display:none`

then to show it use `display:inline-block`

that should work on ei8/9 and above

Comment: I added your changes suggested it still didm't work on IE8. Think it has to do with the hover property.